# Extract data from two tables of DB2 database and load into a temporary table

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am creating an informatica workflow which can extract data from two tables of DB2 database and load into a temporary table. Suppose the two source tables name are Account (Parent) and Activities (Child). They have 1:M relationship. Means an Account can have many Activities (Account.PK = Activities.FK). Activities table has two columns- first 'Type' whose value could be 'Paid', 'Will-Pay' or 'Not-Paid'.And second column is 'Created_Date' datetime datatype, whenever you create new activity record, date and time would get stamp in this field. Now, condition to load data in temporary table is - "For an Account record, it would 1st check in Activities table for today's Paid activities (Type = Paid). If it finds more than one paid activities, then it would pick the Latest created one (Created_Date column) out of them. If there is no Paid activity record for the Account, then it would pick latest created 'Will-Pay' activity." Means, it should pick latest Paid activity for today (Sysdate) for an Account, if it is not present then only It will pick latest Will-pay activity for today. Please help me to understand how I can implement this logic in Informatica workflow and which transformations I should use and how? Thanks alot. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it on SQL cause realize business logic on ETL it's not good. But if you insist it can be created by many ways. As example:

With SQL override
You can create 3 lookup transformation for Activities table with overrided SQL (and columns too) and one expression transformation for condition.

1. Lookup to find more than one 'paid' activities accounts
2. Lookup to find last 'paid' activity per account
3. Lookup to find last 'will pay' activity per account
4. Expression to return correct Activities key based from 1-3 lookup results

Without SQL override you need to recreate similar logic with filter, aggregator, joiner transformations.